# Resize fullcalendar monthly view, day tab in wordpress

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to re-size the cell height in the monthly view on the fullcallendar wordpress plugin.

I know it is affected my the aspect ration, but i would like to customize it to be half of the width of the cell.

Please help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize the FullCalendar by writing the CSS for the Calendar Element. Take a look at the code below.

HTML:

```
<div id='myCalendar'></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Code for adding Dynamic Event. Ignore this code part
    var myEvents = [];
    var date = new Date();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var length = 12;

    for (var month = 1; month < length; month++) {
        var month = (month <= 9) ? '0' + month : month;
        var startdate = y + '-' + month + '-10';
        var enddate = y + '-' + month + '-15';
        myEvents.push({
            title: 'event',
            start: startdate,
            end: enddate,
            allDay: true
        });
    }

    $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({events: myEvents});

});
```

CSS:

```
#myCalendar{margin-top:50px;width:300px;}
```

Demo URL: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsunvtech/pBke3/